# Какой частью речи является " всё" ?

Tags: части-речи

Функцию какой части речи выполняет определительное местоимение ВСЁ в предложениях:

1. Ты уже всё?
2. Бабушке становилось всё легче и легче.
3. Не всё коту масленица.

Comment: Исправили бы заголовок вопроса. А то не по-русски как-то: местоимение *выполняет* часть речи...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тоже не вполне согласен с Виктором. По-моему, в первом предложении *"всё"* — местоимение, выполняющее роль сказуемого, так как оно явно заменяет, например, *"готов"*, *"закончил"* и т.п.

Comment: Согласна,только мы говорим о части речи, а не о члене предложения,речь идет об известном и говорящему, и слушающему действии , которое должно быть выполнено в полном объеме. Иными словами, местоимение всё здесь аналогично глаголу совершенного вида, обозначающему, что действие завершено,

Comment: Извините, я хотел сказать "местоимение, выполняющее роль сказуемого". Сейчас исправлю. Частица не может выполнять его функции.

Comment: А разве в первом предложении слово "всё" не соответствует по смыслу утвердительной частице "да"?

Comment: Нет, совсем нет.

Answer (score 1):

В 1-м и 2-м предложениях "всё" выполняет роль  частицы, а в 3-м - местоименного наречия

Comment: Со 2 и 3 согласна, с 1 нет.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ты уже всё (закончил)?   Местоимение ВСЁ в значении сказуемого. Сравнить: всё, можете идти; всё, больше не увидимся
2. Бабушке становилось всё легче и легче. Местоимение ВСЁ переходит в наречие со значением нарастания  признака, выступает в роли обстоятельства меры и степени.
3. Не всё коту масленица. Местоимение ВСЁ переходит в наречие со значением « всё время», выступает в роли обстоятельства времени.

Comment: 2- усилительная частица при сравнительной степени.

Answer (score 0):

1- сказуемое
2- частица
3- наречие

Comment: Сказуемое — это синтаксическая роль, а не часть речи.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю кто тут сидит, но явно не филологи. Есть дельные мысли, но не до конца.
1 случай - местоимение определительное (выполняет роль сказуемого - обозначает конец действия) NB: для отдельных персон - сказуемое не часть речи, а член предложения.
2 случай - частица модальная усилительная (усиление значения, в данном случае указывает на постоянное усиление признака)
3 случай - наречие (в значении "всегда", "постоянно")

Answer (score 0):

1- местоимение
2- местоимение
3- наречие